# Plotting a loop of plots in Sweave/latex

Tags: r, plot, latex, sweave

Suppose I have a function

```
plotSingle <- function(x) {
   plot(x)
}
```

I want to use this in a loop in `Sweave` to generate 20 pages with 1 plot on each page. For example:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{}
\centering
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
for(loop in 1:20) {
    plotSingle(loop)
    cat('\\newpage')
}
@
\end{figure}
```

However, this will only generate 1 plot on 1 page, not the 20 on 20 pages that I'm after.

How do I adjust the above `Sweave` code in order to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `plot.new` or its alias `frame()` and no need to to `cat('\\newpage')`

```
<<,fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
plotSingle <- function(x) {
   plot.new()   ##  ~ frame()
   plot(0)
}
for(i in 1:3) plotSingle(mtcars)
@
```

**EDIT** with layout:

I think that knitr do some optimizations when he found the same plot statement. That

```
<<,echo=FALSE>>=

plotSingle <- function(x) {

   layout(matrix(1:3,nrow=3))
   plot(0,main=x)          ## the 3 plots statement here are different
   plot(1,main=x)          ## you can just change the title also and it will works
   plot(2,main=x)          ## keep in mind to give knitr different plot statement.

}

 for(i in 1:5)  plotSingle(i)  ## you have also to give different iodex here
                               ## plotSingle(0) will not work for example.
@
```

Comment: What if this `plotSingle` function actually plots a `layout` plot that contains 3 subplots in the same device?

Comment: @user2763361 good catch. I edit my answer. I hope it is clear.